# Passing exception from delayed_job to controller - using caching(memcached)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, exception, ruby-on-rails-3.1, memcached, delayed-job

I am trying to use the `error` hook in delayed jobs to pass an exception to my controller, by using Rails.cache (tied to Memcached).

My controller method has the following line of code, and I have tested that the job is functioning properly:

```
Delayed::Job.enqueue(BuildDetail.new)
```

The BuildDetail class is defined in my /lib/jobs/build_detail.rb file:

```
class BuildDetail

  def perform
    # do some stuff here
  end

  def success(job)
    Rails.cache.write("job_done", true, :expires_in => 4.hours)
  end

  def error(job, exception)
    Rails.cache.write("job_errors", exception, :expires_in => 4.hours)
  end
```

Then in another controller method, I want to be able to do something like the following:

```
def other_controller_method
  job_errors = Rails.cache.read("job_errors")

  case job_errors
    when Timeout::Error
      redirect_to reports_path
      flash[:error] = "You have timed out!"
    else
  #...something else here
  end

end
```

However, I can't seem to access the error messages from the cache key for the case statement. What am I doing wrong? What format are exceptions saved in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with some help, I've figured out that saving the background job exception in a cache key is a very viable solution. From there, I've done a couple of different things - handling some of the errors with JQuery, and some with the actual Rails server. My issue was (in being new to Rails) that I'd forgotten that an exception is a specific object type - and was assuming I could pass the cache value and reference it as a string.